# UITextfield don't show the content when editing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

[image]

Hi,I have get a problem.
I custom a textfield like the second textfield in the pic,override the  function

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.bounds byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerAllCorners cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(self.h / 2, self.h / 2)];
    path.lineWidth = 0.5;
    [[UIColor lightGrayColor] setStroke];
    [path stroke];

}

-(CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {

    return CGRectMake(self.h / 2, self.h, self.w - self.h, self.h); 
}
```

When I editing in the custom textfield,the content is not show in it,and i end edit it,the content show. The first textfield is the system style that works fine.
Hope someone could help me solve the problem, tks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
  return CGRectOffset(bounds, 0, 0);
}

- (CGRect)placeholderRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
  return [self textRectForBounds:bounds];
}

- (CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
  return [self textRectForBounds:bounds];
}
```

Use constants instead of zeros to set custom offset in your code